# possible to sort facebook friends birthdays from a graph api fetch?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

If I am using the following to get my friends birthdays:

```
$facebook->api('/me/friends/?fields=id,first_name,last_name,birthday,picture');
```

is it possible to sort the result by descending birthdays? (soonest is first)

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using an FQL request:

```
$facebook->api('/me/fql?q=SELECT+uid,first_name,last_name,birthday_date,pic+FROM+user+WHERE+uid+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+=+me())+order+by birthday_date');
```

Keep in mind that not everyone provides a birthday and birthday_date values can be ***null***.